# Append items to multiple lists with a single statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like this in Python:

```
my_dict = {'first': [], 'second': [], 'third': []}
```

As you can see, it has two lists inside. I would like to add items to each list with one like/statement, which would be something like this:

```
my_dict['first', 'second'].append([1,2])
```

So the result after this code would be: `{'first': [1], 'second': [2], 'third': []}`

Is there some easy way to make this? I am really trying to avoid for loops.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to avoid for loops? Note that any solution to this question will still use loops internally. For something simpler you could do `my_dict.update(zip(['first', 'second'], [1,2]))`, but your use case is rather unusual, so probably no ready solution exists.

Comment: What is the use case for this? This method would not appear to be anymore efficient than calling ```my_dict['first'].append(1) my_dict['second'].append(2)```

Answer (score 1):

### Iterate Through Dictionary Keys

You can iterate through your dictionary's keys, appending the new item to each dictionary value. For example:

```
new_item = 'foo'
for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key].append(new_item)

my_dict
# {'first': ['foo'], 'second': ['foo'], 'third': ['foo']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usecase is strange but you can try something like this.

```
class CustomDict(defaultdict):
    def append(self, keys, values):
        for key, value in zip(keys, values):
            self[key].append(value)


k = CustomDict(list)
k.append(keys=["first", "second"], values=[1, 2])
```